# Show thumbnail of YouTube video in canvas using pytube and tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, youtube, pytube

I want to show a yt video's thumbnail using tkinter and pytube but it won't work.
My code is as follows:

```
from tkinter import *
import urllib.request, io
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from pytube import YouTube


sc= Tk()

def show_pic():
    yt = YouTube('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sVPYIRF9RCQ')
    raw_data = urllib.request.urlopen(yt.thumbnail_url).read()
    im = Image.open(io.BytesIO(raw_data)).resize((200, 200))
    image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)
    c.create_image(0,0, anchor='nw', image=image)

c = Canvas(sc, width=200, height=200)
c.pack()

btn = Button(sc, text='Show', command=show_pic)
btn.pack()



sc.mainloop()
```

Comment: There should be a reference to images created in a function. Say `global image` inside the func.

Comment: problem solved tnx

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import urllib.request
from io import BytesIO

root = tk.Tk()
URL = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sVPYIRF9RCQ" #imageurl
u = urllib.request.urlopen(URL)
raw_data = u.read()
u.close()
canvas = Canvas(root, width = 300, height = 300)     

im = Image.open(BytesIO(raw_data))
im = im.resize((50,50),Image.ANTIALIAS)
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)

canvas.create_image(20,20, anchor=NW, image=photo)   
root.mainloop()
```